# How can I solve Attempt to read property "id" error, while I am trying to get the last descended row in one of the joined tables in laravel 8?

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I have joined two tables in laravel 8 and now I have one to many relation between two of them in phpMyadmin. I retrieved data from both tables, but in the second tables which attributed to many I only need last registered row. I tried this, but it gives me error when I use first function.

```
$search = $request->re_search;
$search_result = DB::table('projects')->
    join('project__reports','projects.id',"=",'project__reports.project_id')
    ->select('projects.id','projects.Pmid','projects.Ministry',
    'projects.P_name','projects.Budget','project__reports.prgs_prc',
    'project__reports.observers','project__reports.added_fund','project__reports.Registered_at')
     ->where('projects.Ministry','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
     -> orderBy('project__reports.Registered_at','desc')
     ->first();
     // ->get();
```

I also used `latest()` function instead of `orderBy`, but it did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your `'project__reports.project_id'` on the select statement.

```
$search = $request->re_search;
$search_result = DB::table('projects')->

join('project__reports','projects.id',"=",'project__reports.project_id')
->select('projects.id','projects.Pmid','projects.Ministry',
'projects.P_name','projects.Budget','project__reports.prgs_prc',
'project__reports.observers','project__reports.added_fund','project__reports.project_id','project__reports.Registered_at')
 ->where('projects.Ministry','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
 ->orderBy('project__reports.Registered_at','desc')->first();
```

Comment: you mean, right after first()->project__reports.project_id; is that correct?

Comment: yeap, its workable as well

Comment: first()->project_id. The above code you mention most likely will give you an error

Comment: it gives me undefined property error:stdclass:$project_reports